# Git stash deleted changes with `no local changes to save`

Tags: git

Git stash deleted my local changes. Can someone explain why this happend?

Here's a log of my actions:

- I was on branch `feature` with local changes.
- `git checkout develop`

  - Changes were move over to branch `develop`
  - Branch `feature` contains the same files as branch `develop`.
- `git stash` -> Output: `no local changes to save`. (Already suspicious)
- `git status` -> *not local changes*
- `git stash pop`

  - *Expected*: Getting back my local changes from before
  - *Actual*: My changes were gone.

Edit Notes:

- `feature` branch: formerly *branch A*.
- `develop` branch: formerly *branch B*.

Comment: You didn't have local changes which `git stash` could save. Maybe branch B doesn't contain the files which you changed in branch A?

Comment: And in which of these steps were changes "deleted"? What exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: if said modifications were *staged*, and the content of said files exactly matched the content of files on branch `B`, then git will accept to switch to branch `B` and just keep that content for each of these files (which will now appear as unmodified). Did you by any chance run `git status` after "Changes were move over to branch B" ? could it be that the files on B already have the changes you wanted ?

Comment: @mkrieger1 (1) Files in A and B are the same (except for the changes) (2) The files were gone at the very end (see: *actual*); But I guess they were deleted when I called `git stash`

Comment: @LeGEC Branch B did not have the changes I wanted. (I don't remember if/if not I ran git, but I know 100% that the changes weren't in B. (A was a feature branch of B)

Comment: I changed the branch names in the question to something more useful.